# a tag is missing in the navbar

Tags: php, html

I want to pass the user_id to another page and My a tag is missing when I included it in my while statement(mysqli_fetch_array)
I don't know what causes the problem

here is my code:

```
  <?php
              $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
             if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0)
             {
           
             
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                  $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
                    $username = $row['username'];
                    $user_id = $row['id'];
                    $user_type = $row['user_type'];
                    $_POST['id'] = $id;
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $user_id;
              $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
              $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
                    
         
         
              ?>
 
          <li>
          <?php
          echo "<a href='scheduling.php?id=$id'>Schedules</a> ";
        }
        }
              ?>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `echo` statement to this:

```
echo "<a href='scheduling.php?id=".$id."'>Schedules</a> ";
```